# Launching C program from eclipse juno in windows command line

Tags: c, eclipse, cmd

I have a very simple C console project that i programmed in eclipse juno (CDT plugin and mingw64 gcc compiler) I found that the eclipse console is treated like a file so when i call a `printf` function, it **will not** flush the buffer until told so explicitly.
I found that if i run the program from the command line directly then the buffer is flushed as it should. So..... i need to find a way to start my program from eclipse to run in the command line. I found solutions that i didn't really understand and solutions that i think are necessary (a batch file to run via the eclipse).
I'm looking for a more configurable solution such as specifying the `cmd.exe` somewhere in the project properties or creating a run configuration where I specify the path of the `cmd.exe`. 
does anyone know such a way?